# Select users based on the column values - pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, conditional-statements

I am having a problem with selecting IDs that are conforming to some condtions in my dataframe. 
Here is the problem:
My dataframe look like this:

```
index    ID    score_1   score_2   ...
   0     22      0          0
   1     22      0          0
   2     22      0          0
   3     23      1          0
   4     23      1          0 
   5     23      1          0
   6     24      0          0
   7     24      0          0
   8     24      0          1
   10    25      0          0
   11    25      0          0
   12    26      0          1
   13    26      0          1
```

What I want to do is to get the number of IDs that have:

- `score_1 == 0` and `score_2 == 0` for all instances - for example `ID == 22` and `ID == 25` fulfill this requirement.
- `score_1 == 0`, but at least one of the rows for a given `ID` has `score_2 == 1` - for example `ID == 24` fulfill this requirement
- `score_1 == 0`, and ALL of the rows for a given `ID` has `score_2 == 1` - for example `ID == 26` fulfill this requirement

Each ID should appear only in ONE of these groups.

I tried using conditional filtering and groupby, but then I get duplicated IDs as it selects only single rows, instead of 'having in mind' users. 
Some of the code I tried:

```
# Create a df with only IDs that have score_1 == 0, group by `ID`
zero_IDs = df[df['score_1'] == 0].groupby(by = 'ID').nunique()
# 'Count' the number of IDs that have only one type of `score_2`
# But this does not differentitate between `0` or `1` values for score_2 column
zero_IDs[(zero_IDs['score_2'] == 1)].shape[0] 
# 'Count' the number of IDs that have at leat one `score_2 == 1`
zero_IDs[(zero_IDs['score_2'] > 1)].shape[0]
```

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: You will have to share the code that you tried.

Comment: I have added the code snippet I tried to use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this? Results are [22 25]  [24]  [26].

```
dfsum = df.groupby('ID').sum()
case1 = dfsum[(dfsum.score_1==0) & (dfsum.score_2==0)].index
case2 = dfsum[(dfsum.score_1==0) & (dfsum.score_2>0) &  (dfsum.score_2<df.groupby('ID').count().score_2)].index  
case3 = dfsum[(dfsum.score_1==0) & (dfsum.score_2>0) &  (dfsum.score_2==df.groupby('ID').count().score_2)].index
print(case1.values)
print(case2.values)
print(case3.values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Newbie here. Tried my best...

```
df['dummy'] = list(range(0,len(df))) #added a column for looping

grp = df.groupby('ID').agg({'score_1' : 'sum' , 'score_2' : 'sum', 'dummy' : 'count'}).reset_index(level=[0])
instance_1 = []
instance_2 = []
instance_3 = []

i = 0
while i < len(grp):
    if(grp.score_1[i] == 0 and grp.score_2[i] == 0):
        instance_1.append(grp.ID[i])
    elif(grp.score_1[i] == 0 and grp.score_2[i] >= 1 and grp.score_2[i] < grp.dummy[i]):
        instance_2.append(grp.ID[i])
    elif(grp.score_1[i] == 0 and grp.score_2[i] == grp.dummy[i]):
        instance_3.append(grp.ID[i])
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

To this problem, the data should be firstly filtered by a flag, then grouby ID, and check the there conditions:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
```

No need to use `print` for each line

```
csv=StringIO("""
index    ID    score_1   score_2
   0     22      0          0
   1     22      0          0
   2     22      0          0
   3     23      1          1
   4     23      1          0 
   5     23      1          0
   6     24      0          0
   7     24      0          0
   8     24      0          1
   10    25      0          0
   11    25      0          0
   12    26      0          1
   13    26      0          1
""")
```

load the data, and here is the code:

```
df=pd.read_csv(csv,sep='\s+',index_col=0)

flag10=df.score_1==0
group=df[flag10].groupby('ID')['score_2']
case1=group.sum()==0
case1[case1]
case2=group.sum()>0
case2[case2]
case2=group.sum()==group.count()
case2[case2]
```

The anwser is:

```
ID
22    True
25    True
Name: score_2, dtype: bool
ID
24    True
26    True
Name: score_2, dtype: bool
ID
26    True
Name: score_2, dtype: bool
```

Hope it helps